# How to change /usr/bin/php to /Applications/AMPPS/php/bin/php on magento?

Tags: php, bin-magento

When I try to run "which php" from my magento root folder , this say: /usr/bin/php

But, I need that this point php to: /Applications/AMPPS/php/bin/php

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found for mac and it worked for me. 
Open Terminal and run following command.

```
    $    export AMPPS_PHP=/Applications/AMPPS/php/bin
    $    export PATH="$AMPPS_PHP:$PATH"
```

Source: http://www.ampps.com/wiki/Installing_Laravel_Framework

Comment: is this permanent or for the current session only?

Answer (score 0):

you can use complete path to run php. In my case file located in **/opt/lampp/bin/php**

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

for you start from root folder

```
/Applications/AMPPS/php/bin/php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```